# Items overriden in list from keyboard thread

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list

[1]I'm having a problem with my keyboard input thread. I'm currently using `fgets` to read input from the keyboard and then store it to a list using `List_add`. Problem is, my program seems to just print the last character that I inputted instead of the different strings of messages.

UPDATE:
Code in keyboardinput Thread

```
#define MAX_LEN 258

static pthread_t keyboardThread;
static pthread_mutex_t *psharedMutex;
static List* pList;

void* inputFunction(void* unused){
    printf("Enter message:\n");
    while (1) {         
        char* messageAllocated;
        messageAllocated = malloc(MAX_LEN);

        if(messageAllocated != NULL) {
            //Wait for user input
            fgets(messageAllocated, MAX_LEN, stdin);      // This is how C read something from keyboard

            pthread_mutex_lock(psharedMutex);
            {
                List_add(pList, messageAllocated);                // Add message to list for FCFS
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(psharedMutex);

            if (messageAllocated[0] == '!' && messageAllocated[2] == '\0') {
                break;
            }
            
            memset(messageAllocated, 0, MAX_LEN);
        }
        else {
            printf("Malloc Failed.\n");
        }
            
     };

    return NULL;
}

void KeyboardInput_init(List* myList, pthread_mutex_t *sharedMutex) {
    psharedMutex = sharedMutex;
    pList = myList;
    pthread_create(&keyboardThread, NULL, inputFunction, NULL);

}

void KeyboardInput_shutdown() {

    pthread_join(keyboardThread, NULL);
}
```

Code in main.c

```
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    // Create 2 Lists for transmit and receive
    //List listPool;
    List* outboundList;                         // Used in keyboard and UDP sendto threads
    List* inboundList;                          // Used in screen and UDP recvfrom threads

    outboundList = List_create();
    inboundList = List_create();


    // Receive information for s-talk transmission (ports, machine names)
    setUpSTalkApplication();

    Printer_init();
    Signaller_init();
    Printer_waitForShutdown();
    Signaller_shutdown();

    // Startup Modules
    Receiver_init("Message received on Port ", &sharedMutex, remoteMachineName, hostPort);            // goes before keyboard
    KeyboardInput_init(outboundList, &sharedMutex);
    Sender_init(outboundList, &sharedMutex, &condVar, remoteMachineName, targetPort);
    //ScreenOutput_init(inboundList, &condVar, &sharedMutex);


    // Shutdown Modules
    //ScreenOutput_shutdown();
    KeyboardInput_shutdown();
    Receiver_shutdown();
    Sender_shutdown();


    printf("Done.\n");
    while(List_count(outboundList) != 0) {
        char* x = List_trim(outboundList);
        printf("%s", x);
    };
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(messageAllocated)` gives the size of the pointer and not the size of the buffer it points to. Use `MAX_LEN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should validate the pointer `messageAllocated` after `malloc` and the `sizeof(messageAllocated)` is only `4` or `8` bytes, you should use `MAX_LEN` instead of `sizeof(messageAllocated)`

```
while (1) {
    char * messageAllocated;
    messageAllocated = malloc(MAX_LEN);
    if(messageAllocated != NULL)
    {
        fgets(messageAllocated, MAX_LEN, stdin);
        List_add(pList, messageAllocated)
        if (messageAllocated[0] == '!') {
            break;
        }
      //hope you are doing this before reading another string, or else there will be memory leak
       free(messageAllocated); messageAllocated = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("malloc failed\n");     
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, `sizeof(messageAllocated)` is not 1 byte. It is the size of a pointer. Which is usually 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: So, i changed my code, and its able to store into the list, but when i try to print the contents, the characters are randomly jumbled up. i edited my original post, so you can see my implementation. Weirdly, including the free just makes my program print all "! " again so i use memset for it

Comment: again `sizeof(MAX_LEN)` is wrong just use `fgets(messageAllocated, MAX_LEN, stdin);` and  `memset(messageAllocated, 0, MAX_LEN);` and i dont see `free` in your code, its better to post a complete working code, it will be easier to answer

Comment: So ive updated the answer above. Im trying to use mutexes as well for the threads. Thank you so much for your help!